# restful image upload exception

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a restful interface as shown below. 
I am trying to upload an image using jaxrs interface but I am faced with an error

```
    @POST
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @Path("createUserphotoDirectory/{userid}/{serverName}")
        @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
        public String createUserDirectory(@PathParam("userid") Long userid,
                   @PathParam("serverName") String serverName,
                   MultipartFormDataInput input) {
                System.out.println("1");
               photoService.createServerImages(userid,serverName,input);
               return responseMessageSource.getMessage("SUCCESSFULL_CRATED_ALBUM",null,null);
            }
```

When I request using this form

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>JAX-RS Upload Form</h1>

    <form action="/AlbumApplication/rest/createUserphotoDirectory/1/FeedServer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" size="50" />
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I get this error - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect `(java.lang.RuntimeException: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part).`

---

i forgot to write ,i use Springmvc at mvc side,it may be pertain spring mvc block?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace or other error logging from the server? Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137444/resteasy-and-fileupload-get-no-content-disposition-error may be relevant.

Comment: it doesnot go inside the service when i submit from html page it gives (java.lang.RuntimeException: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part). this error there has no stack trace or log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the REST service signature as the following may solve your problem

```
public String createUserDirectory(@PathParam("userid") Long userid,
         @PathParam("serverName") String serverName, 
         @FormDataParam("uploadedFile") File file,
         @FormDataParam("uploadedFile") FormDataContentDisposition disposition) {
```

Comment: thank you for reply but FormDataContentDisposition  class is inside of jersey ,our projects is working with jax-rs,we cant use jersey and jaxrs together because 2 jar is craching thank you

Comment: Isn't Jersey an implementation of JAX-RS? See http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Main

Comment: yes you are right but fro using FormDataContentDisposition  i need to ad jersey.jar when i add this jar tomcat doesnor run giving too many exception when i erase jersey it runs,i dont understand problem