# html form post submit

Tags: html, image, upload, jax-rs

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>JAX-RS Upload Form</h1>

    <form action="/AlbumApplication/rest/createUserphotoDirectory/1/FeedServer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" size="50" />
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

hi when i submit from html form i take (java.lang.RuntimeException: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part).
please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a java handling error. Your form is fine, but java's handling of the result is the problem.

See [restful image upload exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670768/restful-image-upload-exception)

Comment: this link is belongs to me but i cant find any response thank you watermark